# How to deal with dependencies of subprojects in stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have problems figuring out what is wrong with having a source code dependency in my stack project. Say that I want to test a modified version of the [hsparql](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hsparql) library in my project. A minimal setup would be:

```
stack new mytest simple
mkdir 3rdpary
cd 3rdpary
git clone https://github.com/robstewart57/hsparql
```

Modify `stack.yml` to include the local and modified version of hsparql in my project:

```
packages:
- '.'
- 3rdparty/hsparql

# Dependency packages to be pulled from upstream that are not in the resolver
# (e.g., acme-missiles-0.3)
extra-deps: 
- rdf4h-2.0.0
- hgal-2.0.0.2
```

If I go to the 3rdparty/hsparql folder I can `stack test` without any problem, but from the root of my project I get

```
$ stack test
hsparql-0.2.7: build (lib + test)
Progress: 1/2
--  While building package hsparql-0.2.7 using:
      /home/cebrian/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux/setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.5.0-ghc-7.10.3 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0 build lib:hsparql test:test-hsparql --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file"
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: /home/cebrian/borralodedentro/stack-test/.stack-work/logs/hsparql-0.2.7.log

    Preprocessing library hsparql-0.2.7...
    In-place registering hsparql-0.2.7...
    Preprocessing test suite 'test-hsparql' for hsparql-0.2.7...

    /home/cebrian/borralodedentro/stack-test/3rdparty/hsparql/tests/Database/HSparql/ConnectionTest.hs:10:18:
        Could not find module ‘Data.RDF.TriplesGraph’
        Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

For some reason, the test action is not able to find the library `rdf4h` that's been specified both in the original library and my own `stack.yml`.

I have no idea of what I'm doing wrong so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The reproduction steps are a bit confusing: I suspect there's a typo (`3rdpary` / `3rdparty`) and a missing `cd mytest` as the second step. Also your error messages report `stack-test` as the parent directory of `3rdparty`.

Comment: When calling `stack test` from the project root, stack uses `rdf4h-2.0.0` as specified in the `stack.yaml`. That version of `rdf4h` doesn't include `Data.RDF.TriplesGraph`, thus the error message. When running `stack test` from the `hsparql` directory, stack uses a different `stack.yaml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hsparql author here. Thanks for the report. I've pushed a [commit](https://github.com/robstewart57/hsparql/commit/496ad8dbed4e5ffccbc45c5b3b94df2fc7a08d21) that fixes compatibility with rdf4h >= 2.0.0 . I've pushed a hsparql version bump to 0.2.8 to hackage. The `stack test` command now works as you'd expect:

```
Progress: 1/2Database.HSparql.Connection tests:
  selectQuery: [OK]
  askQuery: [OK]
  constructQuery: [OK]
  describeQuery: [OK]

         Test Cases  Total      
 Passed  4           4          
 Failed  0           0          
 Total   4           4
```